# Where is the source code for CSharpSyntaxVisitor virtual method *declarations* such as VisitQualifiedName, VisitAwaitExpression etc?

Tags: c#

Looking at the [online source for CSharpSyntaxVisitor](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/315c2e149ba7889b0937d872274c33fcbfe9af5f/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Syntax/CSharpSyntaxVisitor.cs) there are just a small number of default members.

Implementing a CSharpSyntaxWalker, which derives from CSharpSyntaxVisitor, there are many virtual methods to override, for visiting syntax elements in C#.

Where are these defined/declared?

CSharpSyntaxVisitor is implemented as a partial class, but searching on github I was unable to locate where the basic version of the class is extended with the syntax elements.

Can someone please help point me to where this stuff is defined?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Syntax/CSharpSyntaxRewriter.cs

Comment: Also, it's easier to view the Roslyn source with https://sourceroslyn.io

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks but that link does not seem to be relevant to the question?

Comment: @canton7 Just tried it and cannot find the declaration of, for example, VisitAssignmentExpression.  Only overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find them in [`Syntax.xml.Main.Generated.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Generated/CSharpSyntaxGenerator/CSharpSyntaxGenerator.SourceGenerator/Syntax.xml.Main.Generated.cs). This code used to be generated by a tool, from a file called [`Syntax.xml`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/7ba92d6c1caa1096c7626f72f51b0f619b675218/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Syntax/Syntax.xml).

These days, it looks like it's generated using a [Source Generator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/). The source generator is called [`SourceGenerator`](https://sourceroslyn.io/#CSharpSyntaxGenerator/SourceGenerator.cs,25), and the bit which generates the additional partial class for `CSharpSyntaxVisitor` containing those extra `Visit` methods [is here](https://sourceroslyn.io/#CSharpSyntaxGenerator/SourceWriter.cs,1166). It still reads its input from `Syntax.xml`.